# HTML and JavaScript code do not work together properly

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, debugging

For a school project, I am required to take an input from the user with my website I created with HTML code. After the user presses the "add a new book" submit button the JavaScript should be able to store the value entered inside of the variable and alert the user with it, however, it does not work.

I found a temporarily solution which is to remove every single form tag except the first and last one except this messes up the format of my code and I am wondering whether there is a better way of solving this issue. My HTML and JS code are included.

Error Message on VS Code displayed -

**Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
at addNewBook (c:\School\Grade 11 Comp Sci\Library Asst\addBook.js:4:45)
at onclick (c:\School\Grade 11 Comp Sci\Library Asst\libraryInterface.html:61:184)
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'**

P.S. - The file name of the JavaScript file is 'addBook.JS' and both HTML and JS files are saved within the same folder. I also included the script tag at the end of the body tag as I have seen online, but it still does not work.

My HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <!--This is the website's tab display to let the user know which tab they are on-->
    <title>Add a New Book</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--The following code displays the page's heading-->
    <h1><center>Add A New Book</center></h1>
    <br><br>
    <center>
        <!--The following form asks the library technician to input the book's ID #-->
        <form>
            <label for="bookIDNumL">Book ID #:</label>  <input type="number" name="bookIDNumL" id="bookIDNumL" >
        </form>
        <br>
        <!--The following form asks the library technician to input the book's title-->
        <form>
            <label for="bookTitleL">Book Title:</label>  <input type="text" name="bookTitleL" id="bookTitleL" >
        </form>
        <br>
        <!--The following form asks the library technician to input the book's dewey number-->
        <form>
            <label for="deweyNumL">Dewey #:</label>  <input type="number" name="deweyNumL" id="deweyNumL" min="0">
        </form>
        <br>
        <!--The following form asks the library technician to input the book's author's first and last name-->
        <form>
            <label for="authorNameL">Author Name:</label>  <input type="text" name="authorNameL" id="authorNameL">
        </form>
        <br>
        <!--The following form asks the library technician to input the book's type-->
        <form>
            <label for="bookTypeL">Book Type:</label>  <input type="radio" name="bookTypeL" id="nonFiction">  <label for="nonFiction">Non-Fiction</label>  <input type="radio" name="bookTypeL" id="fiction">  <label for="fiction">Fiction</label>  <input type="radio" name="bookTypeL" id="graphicNovel">  <label for="graphicNovel">Graphic Novel</label>
        </form>
        <br>
        <!--The following form asks the library technician to input the book's publication date-->
        <form>
            <label for="pubDateL">Publication Date:</label> <select id="pubDateL" name="pubDateL">
                <option></option>
                <option value="before 2000">Before 2000</option>
                <option value="2001-2005">2001-2005</option>
                <option value="2006-2010">2006-2010</option>
                <option value="2011-2015">2011-2015</option>
                <option value="2016-2020">2016-2020</option>
                <option value="2021-2023">2021-2023</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <br>
        <!--The following form asks the library technician to upload an image of the book's cover-->
        <form>
            <label for="bookCoverL">Book Cover:</label>  <input type="file" name="bookCoverL" id="bookCoverL" value="Upload Book Cover Image">
        </form>
    </center>
    <br><br>
    <!--The following code creates a "back to the homepage" as well as a "add a new book" button to allow the library technician to either go back to the homepage or to add the book with the given information above-->
    <form>
        <input type="submit" value="Back to the Homepage" style="height:50px; width:325px; font-size:30px;">
    </form>
    <form>
        <input onclick = "addNewBook(this.form)" type="submit" value="Add A New Book" style="float:right; height:50px; width:250px; position:relative; top:-50px; font-size:30px;">
    </form>
    <!--The following code creates the images on the top right and left of the webpage-->
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/665225941057036288/xXpVpaZ__400x400.png" style="float:right; position:relative; top:-475px; left:275px; height:250px; width:250px;">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/665225941057036288/xXpVpaZ__400x400.png" style="float:right; position:relative; top:-475px; left:-750px; height:250px; width:250px;">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="addBook.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS Code

```
var libTechBookNum;

function addNewBook(addBookForm) {
libTechBookNum = addBookForm.bookIDNumL.value;
alert(libTechBookNum);
}
```

Comment: You want to have one `<form>` tag, which surrounds all of the form inputs. Right now you have nine different form elements, and the form, which you get, when pressing submit, only contains the submit button. That is why `addBookForm.bookIDNumL` is undefined. There is no `bookIDNumL` in that form.

Comment: In a form tag, if you do not prevent the form from submitting in your JS, it will refresh the page and you will lose your forms data unless you specify what to do with the form submission. Furthermore as Geshode said, if you look all your inputs are surrounded in separate form tags, so `this` is referring to ***that*** *specific* form only, the form that holds your ***button*** which has no such id present. So as you have it, you would have to head up the DOM tree to a parent element, then query the ID form somehow, but that could be easily mitigated by adding one form tag around everything.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple form tags within your HTML code, which might be causing the issue with your JavaScript code. When you have multiple form tags, each form creates a separate form object in the DOM, and the JavaScript code might not be able to access the input values correctly.

One way to fix this issue is to use a single form tag that wraps around all the input fields, and remove the additional form tags within the HTML code. Like this:

```
    <form>
        <label for="bookIDNumL">Book ID #:</label>  <input type="number" name="bookIDNumL" id="bookIDNumL" >
    
        <!--The following form asks the library technician to input the book's title-->
        <label for="bookTitleL">Book Title:</label>  <input type="text" name="bookTitleL" id="bookTitleL" >
    
        <!--The following form asks the library technician to input the book's dewey number-->
        <label for="deweyNumL">Dewey #:</label>  <input type="number" name="deweyNumL" id="deweyNumL" min="0">
    
        <!--The following form asks the library technician to input the book's author's first and last name-->
        <label for="authorNameL">Author Name:</label>  <input type="text" name="authorNameL" id="authorNameL">
    
        <!--The following form asks the library technician to input the book's type-->
        <label for="bookTypeL">Book Type:</label>  <input type="radio" name="bookTypeL" id="nonFiction"> <label for="nonFiction">Non-Fiction</label>  <input type="radio" name="bookTypeL" id="fiction">
     </form>
```